# D3.js Animated Node Diagram with unexpected nodes

Tags: animation, d3.js, transition, diagram

I have a [simple animated node diagram](http://colinwhite.net/Infections/B7.html) showing hospital infections over time. It's modeled on [Mike Bostock's Wealth of Nations](https://github.com/mbostock/bost.ocks.org/blob/gh-pages/mike/nations/index.html) (wonderful work).

I'm trying to understand why I'm seeing nodes 'out ahead' of the nodes being transitioned in the current month. It's a weird thing to try and explain and easier to look at in the diagram itself.

The [code charting doesn't seem complicated](http://colinwhite.net/Infections/chart1.js) (however, I suspect I'm doing something wrong with the grouping).

And the [CSV data itself](http://colinwhite.net/Infections/chart1data.csv) looks pretty clean.

So what's happing to cause the transition() of nodes ahead of the current month?

And more importantly, how can I clean this up to prevent it?

Comment: When using CSVs, everything is read as strings, also numbers. This can lead to weird behaviour such as you're seeing. Have you tried converting all the strings that are numbers to numbers before using them (simply put a `+` before the variable)?

Comment: Unfortunately, hat didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried sorting your data by month before iterating over it?

Comment: Yes. The data is sorted by month ascending.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what's going on there. You could try logging the data at each step to see if the right data is going in.